# fetch records which have current time falls in a range

Tags: sql, database

this is an interview question:
given a database(mysql or equivalent) with each record having columns 'start time' and 'end time'
I was asked to fetch the records where the current system time falls between start and end time. But start and end time are timestamp(YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS). So I am only supposed to look for the ones where time part(HH:MM:SS) falls in the range(obviously the same date never gets repeated :)).

Comment: I guess this interview question is testing your ability to Google? Such a question will only result in a query to find the appropriate date/time function for the _database server being used_ and not actually any capability on the part of the interviewee. If I could, I would downvote the actual interview question.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP BETWEEN start_time and end_time
```

Comment: Not what was asked. He only cares about the time portion of the timestamp. The date portions are not relevant and should be stripped/normalized.

Comment: I just want the time part, but start time is like date-time format in mysql

Answer (score 0):

This question is *highly* database-engine dependent. Pretty much every database has their own functions for this. Saying `mysql or equivalent` in an interview question is about the same as asking if you know those specific mysql functions... which, by the way, of the major databases least resemble the functions actually defined by the standard, in part because of mysql's history of using unix time. MySQL is like the VB6 of databases, and the question strongly indicates that the interviewer is either himself unaware of this, or getting tired of interviewing developers who are unaware of it.

The complete standard sql reference requires a fee to download, but I did find you a reference for the sql-92 standard date and time data types and operations here:

> [SQL 92 Date and Time - Functional Specification](https://web.archive.org/web/20240116102304/https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/design/doc_169)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
  FROM MyTable T
 WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) BETWEEN TIME_TO_SEC(T.start_time)
       AND TIME_TO_SEC(T.end_time)
```

Comment: There you go @Curt. Goofiness-1.

Comment: does time_to_sec take datetime format and convert to time, or secs?